# Sign of work done by spring force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy, conventions, spring

> Two similar springs P and Q have spring constants $K_p$ and $K_q$ such
> that $K_p>K_q$. They are stretched by the same amount. Compare the
> work done by the springs. *(NEET 2015)*

$$W_p=-\frac{1}{2}K_px^2<-\frac{1}{2}K_qx^2=W_q$$

But the answers [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/two-similar-spring-p-and-q-have-spring-constants-kp/) and [here](https://byjus.com/question-answer/two-similar-springs-p-and-q-have-spring-constants-k-p-and-k-q-such/) (as also in a book I have) take the work done by the spring as:
$$W=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$$

The work done *by* the spring should be negative, based on [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/680750/why-is-work-done-in-a-spring-positive), since the force and the displacement are in opposite directions.
Does the question ask about the magnitude of work? Rather than signed work?

Comment: $W_{conservative forces}=-\Delta U$, so your answer is right. It should have been specified in the question whether to consider the sign or not. There's similar ambiguity about work done in thermodynamics questions as well.

Comment: *"Does the question ask about the magnitude of the work?"* You literally wrote the question as: "Compare the work done by the springs."

Comment: @hft Your point is? The OP is confused as to whether the negative sign is to be taken into consideration or not, since the question's answer seems to be only looking at the magnitude.

Comment: @StutiGupta My point is that the answer is obvious and OP's confusion should be directed at whoever wrote the question, not this forum.

Comment: @StutiGupta I mean, OP seems to just want to complain about the question, not learn about the concept. OP should complain to the person who wrote the question...

Comment: The "question writer" is an national authority in India. It was asked in 1995. Asking the person who it is neither easy nor direct.

Comment: @Starlight My point is not that you should *literally* ask the question writer from 1995, my point is that no one here can answer your complaint except the question writer, who presumably does not monitor this forum. So it is pointless to ask us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{2}k x^2$ is the spring potential energy.  Putting energy into the spring reduces the KE of the rest of the system. Work done = change in KE, so the work done by the spring on the rest of the system is negative.

In answer to your question I think the people setting the question are just being sloppy.

Comment: Note that this was an exam question at a national level. And the exact opposite answer (where opposite sign is taken) was also there as an answer option.

Answer (score 1):

The work done by a spring is negative because, as you point out, the direction of the spring restoring force is opposite to the spring displacement.

Comparing the work done by the two springs, the work done by spring $p$ is more negative (less positive) than spring $q$. On the other hand, the magnitude of the work done by spring $p$ is greater than spring $q$. Thus potential energy, as scalar quantity, stored in spring $p$ is greater than spring $q$.

Although the question is, in my opinion, poorly worded, it asks to compare the work done by the springs, not the magnitude of the work done by the springs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

System - spring

> They are stretched by the same amount.

Implies that external force(s) due to things outside the system stretched the springs and the direction of the external force and the direction of the extension were the same, thus the external force(s) did **positive** work on the spring(s).

Using Newton's third law the force on things outside the system due to the spring is in the opposite direction to the direction of the extension of the spring and hence the spring does **negative** work.

All this proves the point that it is very difficult to set unambiguous questions, (*Does the question ask about the magnitude of work? Rather than signed work?*),  in an examination and this being the case, perhaps too often, an incorrect answers is designated the correct answer in a mark scheme.